# LINQ-to-SQL: SAME REFERENCE CONSTRAINT with trigger

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, triggers

I have a table that references itself in my SQL Server database, which I use with LINQ-to-SQL.

I have created a trigger on this table to handle deletion of rows.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgDeleteCalculation]
ON [dbo].[Calculation]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Calculation WHERE CalcParentId IN (SELECT CalculationId FROM deleted)
    DELETE FROM Calculation WHERE CalculationId IN (SELECT CalculationId FROM deleted)
END
```

The problem occurs when I try to perform a delete in the DataModel.

When I do this, I get the following exception:
The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_calculations_calculations". The conflict occurred in database "DesignDb", table "dbo.Calculation", column 'CalcParentId'.
The statement has been terminated.

I suspect that the trigger isn't triggered...

Is this the case, or could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the child records you're deleting in the first delete query is a parent row for another child row.

Check out this post:

[Self referencing foreign-key constraints and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416926/self-referencing-foreign-key-constraints-and-delete)

Comment: Shouldn't the trigger take care of that? I assume that the trigger is run when a child-row is deleted as well, which then deletes all child-records of that and so on...? Simple recursion (or at least it should be).

Comment: From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx): If an INSTEAD OF trigger defined on a table executes a statement against the table that would ordinarily fire the INSTEAD OF trigger again, the trigger is not called recursively. Instead, the statement is processed as if the table had no INSTEAD OF trigger and starts the chain of constraint operations and AFTER trigger executions

Comment: Ah, ok. So the trigger is pretty much useless in my case? I'm considering to leave the whole idea behind and use the LINQ to SQL DataModel to delete all the rows recursively...

Comment: The SO post I referenced in my answer shows how to use a trigger for this

Comment: (Correct me if I'm wrong) The trigger in the post you are referring to sets the foreign key to null and doesn't actually delete it. As far as I can see, it isn't recursive either.