# Cascade delete a table without the foreign key (parent key has a reference to the child key)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got some poorly designed tables to work with.

I've got a parent table
Table1

```
ParentId| ChildId
1       | 1
2       | NULL
3       | 2
```

The child foreign key is nullable. The child table also has no foreign key relationship to the parent.

Is there a Cascade delete option that once the parent is deleted, it will also delete the child? If not what other options might I have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self referencing foreign-key constraints and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416926/self-referencing-foreign-key-constraints-and-delete)

Answer (score 0):

Write a TRIGGER on the parent table and if the value is deleted and there are no more rows with that child value then DELETE the value from the child table

Comment: I was really hoping I wouldn't have to go the Trigger route but it's probably the only way to handle it.

Comment: @user15124099 the only way SQL Server can know about a relationship is if you tell it, since you haven't how would it know to cascade anything?